# React App Crashes when viewed through Facebook Webview

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Encountering a bizarre issue where our site works on all mobile devices and browsers, but crashes when accessed through Facebook or Instagram's webview on mobile on Android (iPhone works). For instance when the site is accessed through our Facebook our Instagram bio or when sent through messenger.

Seems to be no information or way to debug this.

We're using React and Webpack.

Here's our package.json

`

```
{
  "name": "omnious.com",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Homepage for Omnious",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/omniousstudio/omnious.com",
  "author": "Omnious Dev Team <dev@omnious.com> (https://www.omnious.com)",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://bitbucket.org/omniousstudio/omnious.com.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/omniousstudio/omnious.com/issues"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "omnious"
  ],
  "main": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "node scripts/analyze.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "dev": "node scripts/dev.js",
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "^2.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "happypack": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "koa": "^2.3.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.0",
    "koa-compress": "^2.0.0",
    "koa-helmet": "^3.2.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.2.1",
    "koa-static": "^4.0.1",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.7.0",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "offline-plugin": "^4.8.3",
    "ora": "^1.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-modal": "^2.2.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-remarkable": "^1.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "styled-components": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint-config-omnious": "^0.2.3",
    "eslint-config-omnious-react": "^0.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9"
  }
}
```

`

Comment: List of supported features in WebKit: https://webkit.org/status/

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else is running into this, the issue was we were using object tags for SVG in react. Facebook's Android browser does not support object tags and crashes.

Comment: How did you debug/diagnose the problem?